# To find the sum of the series $\,1+ \frac{1}{3\cdot4}+\frac{1}{5\cdot4^2}+\frac{1}{7\cdot4^3}+\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The answer given is $\log 3$. 
Now looking at the series

\begin{align}
1+ \dfrac{1}{3\cdot4}+\dfrac{1}{5\cdot4^2}+\dfrac{1}{7\cdot4^3}+\ldots &=
\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\left(2n-1\right)\cdot4^n}
\\
\log 3 &=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\,2^n}{n}
\end{align}

How do I relate these two series?

Comment: Your series for $\log 3$ does not converge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** a common series that is used for computing log of any real number is
$$
\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=2\left(x+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5+\frac{x^7}7+\dots\right)
$$
$u=\frac{1+x}{1-x}\iff x=\frac{u-1}{u+1}$

Comment: How can this be derived?

Comment: @zz20s: from the series for $\log(1+x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}k$

Comment: Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @zz20s: $\log(1-x)=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k$

Comment: @zz20s: then subtract: $$\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+(-1)^{k-1}\right)\frac{x^k}k$$ now compute $1+(-1)^{k-1}$ for even and odd $k$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. +1

Answer (score 7):

**hint**: You want to know $S(\frac{1}{2})$ whereas $S(x) = 2\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}, |x| < 1$, $S'(x) = ...$

Answer (score 5):

HINT... consider the series for $\ln(1+x)$ and $\ln(1-x)$

Answer (score 1):

hint

Consider the power series
$$
f(x) := \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{2n-1}
$$
Investigate what differential equation it satisfies.  Looking at it suggests that this is
maybe easier for
$$
g(x) := \frac{f(x^2)}{x} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}
$$